# How to Deserialize null response in js-data

Tags: json-api, jsdata, js-data-angular

The [find method](https://github.com/js-data/js-data-http/blob/6251c6ea6a37a12fe2811a1979d5aa2998b735c2/src/index.js#L238) in js-data-http appears to have a special case where if `item` is *falsey* then it will reject the promise, otherwise it returns `item`. My problem is that some *falsey* values (`0`, `null`, `''`) are valid responses from my API.

For example if I ask for a relation that hasn't been set then the API responds with data `null` wrapped in a jsonapi envelope. This follows the [jsonapi spec](http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-relationships-responses-200) for fetching empty relationships:

```
{
  "links": {
    "self": "/articles/1/relationships/author",
    "related": "/articles/1/author"
  },
  "data": null
}
```

I'm using the [js-data-jsonapi](https://github.com/BlairAllegroTech/js-data-jsonapi) library to help js-data and jsonapi get along. In that library the [DeSerializer](https://github.com/BlairAllegroTech/js-data-jsonapi/blob/js-data-jsonapi/src/JsonApiSerializer.ts#L550) unwraps the jsonapi envelop. At that point js-data is back in charge and the unwrapped data `null` is the value for `item` in the find promise resolve method which causes js-data-http to reject the promise.

Right now I'm taking advantage of a [special case in js-data-jsonapi](https://github.com/rgant/js-data-jsonapi/blob/deserialize-null/src/JsonApiSerializer.ts#L551) to deserialize null data as an array because in JS Arrays are *truthy*. But then I must special case the detection for hasOne relations where now an empty array must be [re-converted into null](https://github.com/rgant/js-data-jsonapi/blob/deserialize-null/src/JsonApiSerializer.ts#L1481).

This seems like an overly complicated way of handling things, is there a better way that I am missing?

My setup uses:

```
"angular": "1.5.8",
"js-data": "2.9.0",
"js-data-angular": "3.2.1",
"js-data-jsonapi": "0.0.0-alpha.21",
```

Comment: It seems that [js-data](https://github.com/js-data/js-data/blob/2.9.0/src/datastore/sync_methods/inject.js#L315) and [js-data-http](https://github.com/js-data/js-data-http/blob/2.2.2/src/index.js#L238) both care strongly about the _falsinisity_ of the response from the server.

Comment: Can you provide details such as what version of js-data and js-data-http you're using?

Note that `find` no longer throws on falsy values in JSData 3.x

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how js-data-http is involved, the error I get is stacktraced to js-data-angular, but in the repos the error message ("Not Found!") doesn't exist in js-data-angular, but it does in js-data-http so I assume there is some build magic.

Comment: @Rob your stacktrace probably looks like it's coming from js-data-angular because that's where the promise resolves/catches. Stacktraces when promises are involved can be illusive.

Comment: @CoryRobinson that could be the case, but I'm not actually using js-data-http in my app. At least not directly installed by npm. I think I have js-data setup to use Angular's $http.